# Unity ARCore touch Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I am currently trying, to detect if a touch input hits a 3D Object in my ARCore scene. I simply edited the HelloAR sample script, to use a custom prefab instead of the andy object, and after i have spawned it, i want to be able to touch it. The prefab consists of six 3D platforms, each with a different name and a box collider. The following code gives very weird results.

```
        if (Frame.Raycast(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, raycastFilter, out hit))
        {
            // Use hit pose and camera pose to check if hittest is from the
            // back of the plane, if it is, no need to create the anchor.
            if ((hit.Trackable is DetectedPlane) &&
                Vector3.Dot(FirstPersonCamera.transform.position - hit.Pose.position,
                    hit.Pose.rotation * Vector3.up) < 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit at back of the current DetectedPlane");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!IsPointerOverUIObject())
                {
                    if(!platsSpawned)
                    {
                        // Instantiate platforms at the hit pose.
                        var platforms = Instantiate(platformPrefab, new Vector3(hit.Pose.position.x, hit.Pose.position.y + offsetY, hit.Pose.position.z), hit.Pose.rotation);

                        // Create an anchor to allow ARCore to track the hitpoint as understanding of the physical
                        // world evolves.
                        var anchor = hit.Trackable.CreateAnchor(hit.Pose);

                        // Make platforms a child of the anchor.
                        platforms.transform.parent = anchor.transform;

                        platsSpawned = true;

                    }
                    else if (platsSpawned)
                    {
                        //Ray raycast = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                        Ray raycast = FirstPersonCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
                        RaycastHit raycastHit;

                        if (Physics.Raycast(raycast, out raycastHit))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                debugLabel.text = raycastHit.collider.name;
                                var obj = GameObject.Find(raycastHit.collider.name);
                                obj.GetComponent<SomeScript>().DoeSmthng();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                Debug.Log(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }
```

Running this code, it will sometimes not hit any platform (even though you are clearly touching them), sometimes it will detect the touch correctly and sometimes it will just hit any of the other platforms in the prefab (even when only one is visible at the moment).

I feel like there is something weird going on with the Raycast. I tried casting with "Camera.main" and "FirstPersonCamera" but the results are pretty much the same.

Any ideas on why this is happening? Does someone have a proper example or can help me to correct my code ?

EDIT: I found out that the RayCasts work as long as the platform Objects are not children of the anchor. I that maybe the Objects might be turned into "Trackables", but i am not sure how i would work with those.

Comment: Maybe due to multitouch.Input.GetTouch(0).position maybe not your need.I guess.

Comment: So you suggest, that i am allready touching the screen somewhere else when i try to touch the object? That could be possible because of infinity Display. How would you suggest to do it then?

Comment: I'm not sure.try Input.multiTouchEnabled = false. And take a test.

Comment: I will try that in the evening. I'll let u know the result

Comment: Ok so i tried it now and it didn't solve the problem. But i found out, that the problem only occurs when the platform object is a child of the anchor. Does anyone know, how i detect Objects that are children of anchors?

Comment: What ARCore Version are you useing? To clarify, what do you mean with: "(even when only one is visible at the moment)." are not all 6 platforms visible when you set them? Can you post a screenshot of your game view with the platforms and the hierarchy? Are the platforms child objects of an empty game object and that is then the child of the anchor? The Colliders of the platforms don't overlap?

Comment: I am using ARCore v1.4 for unity. When i set the platforms, all of them are visible. I meant that, when i move my device closely to one of the platforms, to ensure that no other platforms are on the screen, it still happens that a different or no collider at all is being hit. Yes the platforms are children of an empty gameobject and that is then the child of the anchor. No the colliders do not overlap.

Comment: Okay and is on the background of all 6 platforms a detected plane visible? Because when your platforms are spawned you only get to your if (Physics.Raycast...) part if your raycastFilter is true. I think you used the standard raycastFilter (PlaneWithinPolygon and FeaturePointWithSurfaceNormal). So if one of your platform isn't over a detected plane you don't perform the physic raycast and you don't get the collider name.